# Cuda over a local network

Tags: networking, cuda

I have the following situation.
I want to split up my cuda program over 2 programs.
The first PC will do the big calculations and gather the data that it needs. 
The second PC some simple calculations + data viewing.
Is there a standard cuda command to send the data over the network. And if not whats the best way to do this?

Comment: i found this already https://developer.nvidia.com/gpudirect but it only works on linux and the pc that I can use for this run on windows - edit in some nvidia documents they say that it works on windows to so i will test that as soon as i have the chanse

Comment: GPUDirect names the feature of CUDA to interop with Melanox InfiniBand hardware reducing memory thransfer overhead for data transfer over IB. AFAIK mvapich2 and OpenMPI are the only libraries with GPUDirect support. For the MPI topic refer to @Roger Dahls answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUDA does not cover network transfer of data. For that, you will typically combine CUDA with some other technology designed for distributed processing, such as [MPI (Message Passing Interface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) or [PVM (Parallel Virtual Machine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Virtual_Machine). To learn more about how to set up distributed computing systems, search the web for "beowulf cluster".